# Selenium webdriver Java: Page object model :Cannot find web elements in chrome browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to execute a simple testng program using page object model. 
    I am able to launch chrome browser. But cannot find any web elements on the page. It is printing foundd and not doing anything after that. Below is the output. Chrome version is 79.0XX. Note that simple java file(without page object model)  is working fine in my system.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESKEu.png)

HomePage class:

```
public class HomePage {
    WebDriver driver;
    By homePageUserName = By.xpath("/html/body/header/div[1]/span[2]/a[1]");

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String getHomePageDashboardUserName(){
        System.out.println("foundd");
        return driver.findElement(homePageUserName).getText();
    }
}
```

TestPage class:

```
import pages.HomePage;

public class TestPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    HomePage objHomePage;

    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest(String browser){
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\jars\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.get("MY URL here");

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    }

    @Test(priority=0)
    public void test_Home_Page_Appear_Correct(){
        objHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
        String PageTitle = objHomePage.getHomePageDashboardUserName();

        if(PageTitle!=null)
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(PageTitle.toLowerCase().contains("us"));
         }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="ChromeTest" parallel="none">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.TestPage">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: You are printing "foundd" when nothing has actually been found. You haven't done any actions in that method yet. In your test, print `PageTitle` before asserting it's contents. What does it print? My guess is that your locator is off.

Comment: Hi, I printed 'foundd' only to verify if control is coming to getHomePageDashboardUserName() function.  My locator By homePageUserName = By.xpath("/html/body/header/div[1]/span[2]/a[1]");
 is a link which has link text as 'About us'. So i'm trying to return that text.If that text is not null, i am checking if text contains 'us' word. Then test should pass. Not sure why its failing. It is not only for that locator, if i try to do any action with other page elements as well, test is failing.

Comment: Did you print `PageTitle` as I asked?

Comment: Yes. I tried . But it’s empty. Not printing anything

Comment: That's why your assert is failing. You need to fix your locator most likely to point to the right element. You may also need to add a wait to make sure the element is loaded before you pull the text.

Comment: Thanks fixed now